# jQuery: wrap numerals inside div in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out if this is at all possible, I have a setup like the markup below:

```
<div class="price-wrap">£12.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">from £9.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">£6.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">£16.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">£11.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">from £1.95</div>
```

but what I'm ideally after, if possible is something like this:

```
<div class="price-wrap">£<span class="price">12.95</span></div>
<div class="price-wrap">from £<span class="price">9.95</span></div>
<div class="price-wrap">£<span class="price">6.95</span></div>
<div class="price-wrap">£<span class="price">16.95</span></div>
<div class="price-wrap">£<span class="price">11.95</span></div>
<div class="price-wrap">from £<span class="price">1.95</span></div>
```

Thus just wrapping the numerals in a `span` tag with the class `price` excluding any `£` or `from` etc etc.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Simple regular expression to split the number part from the rest, and then insert back into the div, wrapped into a span.

Comment: look into :before pseudo-element. have two, one for "from L" and one for "L"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
$('.price-wrap').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/([0-9.]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the contents of each div using a callback in .html():

```js
$('div.price-wrap').html(function () {
    var val = $(this).text().split('£');
    return val[0] + '£<span class="price">' + val[1] + '</span>'
})
```

```css
.price {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-wrap">£12.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">from £9.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">£6.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">£16.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">£11.95</div>
<div class="price-wrap">from £1.95</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use regex and replace the float by `<span>float</span>`

regex to match a float `([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)`

Comment: just providing a regex doesn't really answer the question without showing how to implement it